# How to POST textbox value using <a> tag?

Tags: php, jquery

my question might be little different but my requirement is something like that:

Here is the scenario...

I am having a page which POST all the values to next page on button click. Somthing like this...

```
    <form id="vrmainfrm" name="vrmainfrm" method="POST" action="nvendoraddcode.php">
     <input name="vrname" type="text" id="vrname" value=""/>
       ......
       ......
     <input type="submit" name="vrsubbmit" value="Submit"/>
    </form>
```

Now, I add a link beside vrname and I want to POST vrname's value to another page when I click on 'See Details' link.

I've tried something with AJAX from Google (I am not much aware about AJAX)...

```
<script>
function IsBlank_Post(){
    var x=document.forms["vrmainfrm"]["vrname"].value;
    if (x==null || x==""){
      alert("Company name must be filled out");
      return false;
    }
    else{
        $.ajax({
        term = $form.find( 'input[name="vrname"]' ).val()
        type: "POST",
        url: "nviewdetail.php",
        data: "{ vrname: term }",
        });
    }
}
</script>
    <form id="vrmainfrm" name="vrmainfrm" method="POST" action="nvendoraddcode.php">
     <input name="vrname" type="text" id="vrname" value=""/><a href="javascript:;" onclick="return IsBlank_Post();">See Details</a>
       ......
       ......
     <input type="submit" name="vrsubbmit" value="Submit"/>
    </form>
```

But it's not working! Can any one point out if I am doing in correct way or any other method is there? If yes please share.

Thanks in adv!

**EDIT:**

Hi guys,

I've done with my requirement by passing textbox value through query-string.

Here is code:

```
<script>
    function IsValue_Post(){
       var  vrname = document.vrmainfrm.vrname.value;
       window.location = "nviewdetail.php?cmpname=" + vrname;
      }
</script>

        <form id="vrmainfrm" name="vrmainfrm" method="POST" action="nvendoraddcode.php">
         <input name="vrname" type="text" id="vrname" value=""/><a href="javascript:IsValue_Post();">See Details</a>
           ......
           ......
         <input type="submit" name="vrsubbmit" value="Submit"/>
        </form>
```

And on nviewdetail.php:

```
$searchname=$_REQUEST['cmpname'];
```

As simple as that...Thanks all for your support!

Comment: It might be easier to wrap everything in jQuery functions instead of combining native JS and jQuery. You could use the submit() of jQuery to both submit the form when clicking the a-tag and binding an event to the submitting of the form. See http://api.jquery.com/submit/

Comment: Define: `But it's not working!`. This page is not related to guessing games :)

Comment: Use a Javascript console and fix the errors. Also, you should go to jQuery's website and read any introductory material and tutorials. There is no point in helping you if you do not know how to help yourself first.

Comment: You have a syntax errors. Check your error console next time

Comment: @Andrius Naruševičius - "But it's not working!" means nothing happens when I click on link. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

you have an error in ajax function..var term should be outside the ajax call. data should be object and not string

try this

```
  ...
  else{
   var term = $form.find( 'input[name="vrname"]' ).val();  //<---here declare it outside the ajax
    //or  
  var term =$("#vrname").val(); //<--not sure what $form is but i think this should work
   $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "nviewdetail.php",
    data: { vrname: term }, //<--here this should be object
     success:function(data){  //<--- callback function which is called whn ajax call succeed
         //do your stuff
     }
    });
  }
```

Comment: Thanks @bipen. But it still not posting value. It gives error  'Notice: Undefined index: vrname in C:\wamp\www\VMS\test2.php on line 3'

Comment: I've used, `else{var term =$("#vrname").val();$.ajax({type: "POST",url: "test2.php",data: { vrname: term },success:function(data){window.location.href = "test2.php"; }
 });
 }` and on test2.php I've done `$searchname=$_POST['vrname'];` and `$searchname = $_REQUEST['vrname'];`. But giving errors for both. Any idea?

Comment: `window.location.href = "test2.php";`; remove this line.. why are you redirecting to test2.php again.. ?

Answer (score 0):

Use below code for ajax:

```
function IsBlank_Post(){
    var x = $("#vrname").val();
    if (x==null || x==""){
      alert("Company name must be filled out");
      return false;
    } else {
        $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "nviewdetail.php",
        data: {'vrname': x},
        success: function(returnData){
            alert("Successfull");
            return true;
        }
        });
    }
}
```

And at the page **nviewdetail.php** you can get it by

```
$vrname = $_REQUEST['vename'];
```